# console.log Angular directive scope outputs "[object Object] No Properties"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Looking at the videos over at http://egghead.io, I see the author uses console.log to log out the contents of a $scope or scope object.  The output in Chrome is a drillable object.  However when I do the same, the output Chrome presents is:

```
    [object Object]
No Properties
```

Using console.dir has the same affect.  Any recommendations?

Thanks,

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The + operator calls to the toString method of the object which would return '[object object]'

So using log like this:

```
console.log('scope is ' + scope);
```

Produced the string scope is [object object]

Instead use the console.log() method with commas (as commented below) to be able to drill into the scope object:

```
console.log('scope is', scope)
```

Comment: Or you could do something like: `console.log('object is ', object);`  (you can give multiple arguments.)

Answer (score 3):

Use **console.log(formValues);**
 instead of ***console.log("Values="+formValues);***.
If you use **console.log("Values="+formValues);** ,it is considered as string and output as `[Object object]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.stringify() function to display values of result received from database.

`console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(res));`